# Text Concatenation Issue in VB.Net on text change event in textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to concatenate the text fields in the VB.Net using text boxes on the text change in the text boxes.

Currently I am doing the task on the drop down selection change:

**VB Code**

```
Protected Sub ddlCitizenSex_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlCitizenSex.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ddlCitizenSex.SelectedValue = "Male" Then
        txtCitizenName.Text = 
            txtCitizenFirstName.Text + " " + "S/O" + 
            txtCitizenFatherName.Text + " " + "S/O" + 
            txtCitizenGFatherName.Text + " " + txtCitizenFamilyName.Text
    Else
        txtCitizenName.Text = 
            txtCitizenFirstName.Text + " " + "D/O" +
            txtCitizenFatherName.Text + " " + "S/O" + 
            txtCitizenGFatherName.Text + " " + txtCitizenFamilyName.Text
    End If
End Sub
```

I wrote the following code to try it, but no use:

**VB Code**

```
Private Sub ModifyCitizenName()
    If ddlCitizenSex.SelectedValue = "Male" Then
        txtCitizenName.Text = 
            txtCitizenFirstName.Text + " " + "S/O" + 
            txtCitizenFatherName.Text + " " + "S/O" + 
            txtCitizenGFatherName.Text + " " + txtCitizenFamilyName.Text
    Else
        txtCitizenName.Text = 
            txtCitizenFirstName.Text + " " + "D/O" + 
            txtCitizenFatherName.Text + " " + "S/O" + 
            txtCitizenGFatherName.Text + " " + txtCitizenFamilyName.Text
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub txtCitizenFirstName_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCitizenFirstName.TextChanged
    ModifyCitizenName()
End Sub

Protected Sub txtCitizenFamilyName_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCitizenFamilyName.TextChanged
    ModifyCitizenName()
End Sub
```

**ASP Code**

```
 <asp:Label ID="lblCitizenFamilyName" runat="server"  Text="">Family Name</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCitizenFamilyName"  AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="lblCitizenFirstName" runat="server"  Text="">First Name</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCitizenFirstName"  AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Label ID="lblCitizenSex" runat="server" Text="">Sex</asp:Label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCitizenSex" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

As you can see I used ***AutoPostBack*** in both text boxes.

Should I have to use **`<Triggers>`** for the text boxes.

And how to perform the task. Hope you guys help. Thank you

Comment: When you say "I wrote the following code to try it, but no use" what do you mean? Do you get an error? Is the text box populated with anything?

Comment: @MattWilko Sorry for late reply, but what I mean is that when I am entring some text in `txtCitizenFamilyName` or `txtCitizenFirstName`, Nothing happen.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET will not trigger a postback because a user has edited the contents of a textbox. If it did, then every time you typed a character, you would have to wait about 2 seconds as a full round-trip was performed.

This functionality (updating a text-box with the contents of  would be best implemented client-side, using JavaScript (particularly the jQuery library). [Knockout.js](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro) can also be used to easily add an [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to your `txtCitizenFamilyName` textbox, which will allow you to easily implement this.